# Using "IIFE" to create private scope; do I need parentheses?

Tags: iife

This is my code:

```
var badget = function () {
    var privetVar = 23;
    var privetFunc = function (a) {
        return privetVar + a;
    }
    return {
        publicFunc: function (b) {
            console.log(privetFunc (b));
        }
    }
}();
```

It works well; I have access to the `publicFunc()` using `badget.publicFunc()`, which has access to the `privetVar` and `privetFunc()` due to "closures".

However, someone told me I must use parentheses like this:

```
var badget = (function() {
    var privetVar = 23;
    var privetFunc = function(a) {
        return privetVar + a;
    }
    return {
        publicFunc: function(b) {
            console.log(privetFunc(b));
        }
    }
})();
```

Is this second example considered a preferable syntax?

Answer (score 3):

**No, the parentheses are not required in this example.** Typically people don't use the return value of an IIFE, so the parentheses are required to differentiate a function *expression* from a function *statement*.

Since your function declaration in your first example is already part of an assignment expression, it's already a function expression, so the parentheses aren't required.

### TL;DR

#### Valid

```
var badget = function () {
  ...
}();
```

```
(function () {
  ...
})();
```

```
(function () {
  ...
}());
```

#### Valid (but not necessary)

```
var badget = (function () {
  ...
})();
```

```
var badget = (function () {
  ...
}());
```

#### Invalid (function *statements* cannot be IIFEs)

```
function () {
  ...
}();
```